# Monitor enter error - how to grab the execution

Tags: .net, multithreading

I need to exactly implement the following pattern

```
R-------   ----     ----    ------
W       ----    -----    ----
```

How to implement this using Monitor ? The code below contains the error somewhere but I cant find it, I'm not familiar with the multithreading.

I need the behavior like with fibers, but I can't change the runtime and production code can't use yield return(C# 1.0).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static object o = new object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            Monitor.Enter(o); // make writer wait at start

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => {
                WaitForStart();
                Console.WriteLine("Entering");
                Yield();
                Console.WriteLine("yield 1");
                Yield();
                Console.WriteLine("yield 2");
                Yield();
                Console.WriteLine("yield 3");
                Yield();
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Finishing");
            Start(); // start th writer

            Console.WriteLine("get 1");
            Get();
            Console.WriteLine("get 2");
            Get();
            Console.WriteLine("get 3");
            Get();
            Console.WriteLine("Finishing");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Get()
        {
            Monitor.Enter(o);
            Monitor.Pulse(o);
            Monitor.Exit(o);
        }

        private static void Yield()
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(o);
            Monitor.Exit(o);
            Monitor.Enter(o);
        }

        private static void WaitForStart()
        {
            Monitor.Enter(o);
        }

        private static void Start()
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(o);
            Monitor.Exit(o);
        }


    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want the reader/write threads to produce/consume each item synchronously?  If so, don't use separate threads.

Comment: No idea what this code is trying to do.  Sounds to me you should be using a ReaderWriterLock

Comment: I created a diagram in the message. I don't know how to use readerwritelock to solve the problem.

Comment: Michael, you are right. But I have the threads already separated. I need to make them to work like they are single threag, I.E. like fibers.